# Redirection to another file from one php file from computer on LAN

Tags: php, xampp

I have created a local server on computer-A.
let server ip address is 192.168.1.1 on LAN.

Now i am trying to access file1.php from another computer-B on LAN as:

192.168.1.1/file1.php

In file1.php, i am redirecting to another file named file2.php by using :

header("Location: ./file2.php");

so it should be redirected to 192.168.1.1/file2.php. But it is redirecting to localhost/file2.php.

How to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].'/file1.php');
```

`SERVER_ADDR` returns the ip address of the webpage you're on.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect with the full address like this:

```
header('Location: http://192.168.1.1/file1.php');
```

if you do it, does it have any error?